# Rails - Upload and parse multiple CSV files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Im trying to upload and parse multiple CSV files. What I have so far:

My View

```
 <h3>Upload multiple files</h3>  
  <%= form_tag({:controller => "multi_uploader", :action => "import"}, :multipart => true) do %>
    <em>Upload a tab-separated .txt file to generate new rating sets.</em> <hr/>
    <%= file_field_tag :file_1 %>
     <hr/>
    <%= file_field_tag :file_2 %>
     <hr/>
    <%= file_field_tag :file_3 %>
     <hr/>
    <%= file_field_tag :file_4 %>
     <hr/>
    <%= file_field_tag :file_5 %>
     <hr/>
    <%= file_field_tag :file_6 %>
    <hr/>
    <%= submit_tag "Import Data", :class => "btn btn-link"%>
    <% end %>
```

My Controller:

```
 def import
    unless params[:file_1].nil?
    file_1 = params[:file_1]
    RatingSet.multi_uploader(file_1)
  end
  unless params[:file_2].nil?
    file_2 = params[:file_2]
    RatingSet.multi_uploader(file_2)
  end
  unless params[:file_3].nil?
    file_3 = params[:file_3]
    RatingSet.multi_uploader(file_3)
  end
  unless params[:file_4].nil?
    file_4 = params[:file_4]
    RatingSet.multi_uploader(file_4)
  end
  unless params[:file_5].nil?
    file_5 = params[:file_5]
    RatingSet.multi_uploader(file_5)
  end
  unless params[:file_6].nil?
    file_6 = params[:file_6]
    RatingSet.multi_uploader(file_6)
  end
    redirect_to "/multi_uploader", :flash => { :notice => "Successfully Uploaded." }
  end
```

My Model method to import file:

```
 def self.multi_uploader(file)
    upload = File.open(file.path)  
    #Parse file and save data to db. 
  end
```

In my `multi_uploader` method, I parse out a key (from the file) for which category the file is supposed to be uploaded to. Everything works as expected when I upload a single file, however if I upload multiple files, the contents of all files are being saved for to a single category, rather than multiple categories. Its as if all files are being treated as a single file, rather than n individual files. What can I change to upload each file individually?

Comment: Are you sure each individual file is executing `multi_uploader` once? cause I don't see a reason why this should be happening.

Comment: I believe it is executing the `multi_uploader` method once. If I do a puts in the method for the file name and the category to which it should be uploaded, I get back the correct file names and categories as each file is processed.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the problem is the way you are parsing and saving the files to the db? Cause your form and controller look fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I see. This behavior shouldn't actually be happening. I would suggest another way of doing this code, since it's looking a bit polluted.

```
def import
    (1..x).each do |i| #with x being the max number of files uploaded at the same time
         RatingSet.multi_uploader(params["file_#{i}".to_sym])
    end
    redirect_to "/multi_uploader", :flash => { :notice => "Successfully Uploaded." }
end
```

Either way, this shouldn't solve your problem. I can't tell why this is happening to be honest.

**UPDATE:**

Have you considered using: `<%= f.file_field :file, :multiple => true %>` instead of mutiple file_tags?